# Substrate - cannot find type `Vec` in this scope

Tags: rust, substrate

I'm trying to play around with the substrate node template example and add some custom structs around.

However, I get the following compilation error:

"cannot find type `Vec` in this scope"

And example of the struct being used (+ associated traits and where I'm importing them from) is:

```
    use codec::{Encode, Decode};
    use scale_info::TypeInfo;

    // , WrapperTypeDecode, WrapperTypeEncode, TypeInfo
    #[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, Clone, PartialEq, TypeInfo)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
    pub struct Image {
        // Note: Consider changing to JPG compression in the future
        pixels: Vec<Vec<(u8, u8, u8)>>,
        height: u32,
        width: u32
    }
```

But given that substrate requires quite a lot of bootstrapping I can't provide a working example.

The one thing I tried is adding `#[cfg(feature = "std")]` which afacit should have enabled either the rust std *or* the `std` defined in the `Cargo.toml`, I'm honestly unsure which. But it didn't help.

My main question is... how do I fix this? What imports am I missing where?

My secondary more important question is why would this be happening? Inside the https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/ tutorial `vec!` and `Vec` seem to be used without any issues or further additions... Or rather, the one addition I see is `#[cfg(feature = "std")]` being used before all impl blocks that use `vec!` but not before using `Vec`. Why is this the case? Is this simply allowing a block to import anything from the rust std? Or does it refer to the `std` defined in the `Cargo.toml` ? Why would it be necessary for `vec!` but not `Vec` ?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at CRUST parachain, https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-lfs   or other web3 / IPFS off-chain storage mechanisms.

Generally you want to store as little state on-chain as possible. Storing the image data directly (even as a highly compressed jpeg) would probably not be a great design decision as it could get very expensive (unless your image sizes are very small).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't want to enable `std` when you are working with substrate, as `non-std` is required by SCALE codec, this also enables wasm compilation. More on SCALE [here](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/scale-codec/)

About `Vec`, you might be just lacking using some `frame_support` crate, not much that I can tell just for checking the struct you provided. But I will let you here the storage [entry about runtime storage](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/storage/#storage-items) of the substrate docs.
And would recommend to compare your code with some pallet on the [substrate repo](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame) so you can see from other pallets using `Vec` what you might be missing.
For instance, [nicks pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/nicks/src/lib.rs#L114) stores the nick itself as a `Vec` so that could be a good place to start looking.

Hope this is helpful enough.

Answer (score 1):

What `#[cfg(feature = "std")]` does is "if the Cargo feature of my crate called `std` is enabled, include the code block below. This is a form of conditional compilation. Apparently substrate needs to build the code in no-std contexts too. The parts that need to run in no-std won't be able to use Vec.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding `default-features = false,` in my dependencies in my runtime/Cargo.toml

```
pallet-evm = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", default-features = false, branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }
```